# Combining columns in SAS

Tags: sas

I just started using SAS and I'm trying to combine columns.

I've got table mainData

```
A1 A2 A3 A4
1  4  7  10
2  5  8  11
3  6  9  12
```

I want to create a new table rearrangedData

```
Type Value
A1    1
A1    2
A1    3
A2    4
A2    5
A2    6
A3    7
A3    8
A3    9
A4    10
A4    11
A4    12
```

There must be a simple solution to this I just can't figure this out. I'm thinking of writing do loop, but what if I don't know size of a table or amount of lines in a specific column. I can't figure how I would get such information in SAS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This somewhat unusual transformation can be done via a transpose and some array logic:

```
data have;
input A1 A2 A3 A4;
cards;
1  4  7  10
2  5  8  11
3  6  9  12
;
run;

proc transpose data = have out = tr name=type prefix = r;
run;

data want;
 set tr;
 array r{*} r:;
 do i = 1 to dim(r);
    value = r[i];
    output;
 end;
 drop i r:;
run;
```

Also, this preserves the original order without requiring a sort.

Answer (score 0):

Make a dummy variable, then transpose data.

```
data have;
   set have;
   id=_n_;
run;

proc transpose data=have out=temp;
by id;
var A1-A4;
run;

proc sort data=temp out=want(rename=(_name_=type col1=value) drop=id);
by _name_;
run;
```

Comment: I'd suggest using a view for the first step if the dataset doesn't already have some sort of id column.

Comment: If the first column is unique then it can be used as the BY variable and also included in the list of variables to transpose.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to preserve the original order then you could use the POINT= option on the SET statement to loop over the data set once per variable (column).

So this data set will read the first observations just to get the variables defined. Then define the array `VALUES` so that we can use `DIM(VALUES)` to know how many columns.  Then it uses the `POINT=` and `NOBS=` options on the SET statement to control the other loop.  It uses the `VNAME()` function to find the name of the current variable in the array.

```
data want ;
   set have ;
   array values _numeric_;
   do col=1 to dim(values);
     length type $32 value 8;
     type=vname(values(col));
     do row=1 to nobs ;
        set have point=row nobs=nobs ;
        value=values(col);
        output;
        keep type value;
     end;
   end;
   stop;
run;
```

Comment: Full marks for doing everything in one data step, although it is effectively reading the whole input dataset once per variable.